# Placing marginal label within multiline heading

Tags: sectioning, numbering, margins, boxes

I want to make section headings in an article-class document both multiline and having lables on thier margins.

I'm using two boxes: one for a label and another one for text to force it to split.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
            {\fontsize{28}{24}\headingfont}%format
            {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
                \headingfontlight\thesection\hskip 9pt}}%
            {0pt}
            {\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth][l]{%
                  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
            {\raggedright #1}}}
```

This code works well but has one loose end: a section label is placed in the center of a heading box instead of its top.

[image]

Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\parbox[t]`. Don't use the `explicit` option to `titlesec`, you'll regret it, one day: it's much cleaner to define a separate macro than clobbering the last argument of `\titleformat`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{28}{24}\headingfont}%format
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{\headingfontlight\thesection\hskip 9pt}}%
  {0pt}
  {\printsectiontitle}

\newcommand{\printsectiontitle}[1]{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth][l]{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
      {\raggedright #1}%
  }%
}

\let\headingfont\selectfont % just for the example
\let\headingfontlight\relax

\begin{document}

\section{Some long long long long long long long long long long long long heading}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the purpose of setting the title at 28pt with a baseline skip of 24pt? Just to get too near lines and uneven spacing?

Comment: Thanks! «Just to get too near lines and uneven spacing?» — In my view, a heading with huge font and default spacing looks too wide and difficult to read. For instance, [this heading](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/dvgcwyfatsch0lf/0icf2dzi.png) has 28pt font size and 28pt spacing, and [this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/dvgcwyfatsch0lf/g_0u25aw.png) has 28pt font size and 24pt spacing. In my eyes, the second one is more readable.